# How to delete an class instance inside of an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, class

I am trying to remove a Silverware class inside of the @contents array by rewriting the method "remove_item" inside the drawer class. This method should takes a parameter of the name of the @type of the silverware.

```
class Drawer
attr_reader :contents
    def initialize
        @contents = []
    end
    def add_item(item)
        @contents << item
    end
    def remove_item(item = @contents.pop)
        @contents.delete(item)   # I have to fix this.
    end
end

class Silverware
    attr_reader :type
        def initialize(type, clean = true)
          @type = type
        end
end

silverware_drawer = Drawer.new    # creating new drawer
silverware_drawer.add_item(Silverware.new("spoon"))    # adding silverware
p silverware_drawer.contents    # I get this >> [#<Silverware:0x007f84aa091ad8 @type="spoon",     @clean=true>]

p silverware_drawer.remove_item("spoon")    # removing spoon
p silverware_drawer.contents    # Show drawer and I still get [#<Silverware:0x007f84aa091ad8 @type="spoon",     @clean=true>]
```

Any helps would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing in the object. You are just passing in the type. So you have to find the item with type "spoon" and delete it from the array

```
def remove_item(item)
   @contents.delete(@contents.find{|content| content.type == item})
end
```

Comment: or `@contents = @contents.reject { |content| content.type == item }` or `@contents.reject! { |content| content.type == item }; @contents`.  (Recall that with `reject!`, `nil` is returned if no elements are rejected.)